# What might cause paramiko 'Invalid Packet Blocking' on switch to new keys?

Tags: python, networking, paramiko

I am attempting to create a paramiko sftp server that intigrates with authentication.

I am using WinSCP as a sftp client and finding that the connection drops at the point of accepting the channel, but after initial connection has been made.

The code to accept is:

```
try:
            sftp_logger.info('Starting SFTP Server')
        self.database = DatabaseInterface()
        
        # CONFIGURE A LISTENING SOCKET
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)

        # Get details of running machine
        dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        local_ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

        sock.bind((local_ip, 22))
        sock.listen(10)

        # Configure Paramiko logging
        paramiko.common.logging.basicConfig(level=paramiko.common.DEBUG)

        # Configure Python logging to save logs to a file
        logging.basicConfig(filename='paramiko_debug.log', level=logging.DEBUG)

        # Redirect Paramiko logs to Python logging
        paramiko.common.logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.FileHandler('paramiko_debug.log'))

        sftp_logger.info('Initial Server Set-Up Complete')
        server_key = paramiko.RSAKey.generate(2048)
        sftp_logger.info('Generated Key')

        # Serve indefinitely
        channels = []
        while True:
            
            conn, addr = sock.accept()

            sftp_logger.info(f"Accepted Connection from {str(addr)}")


            transport = paramiko.Transport((conn))
            sftp_logger.debug(f"Initiated Transport for {str(addr)}")
            transport.add_server_key(server_key)
            sftp_logger.debug(f"Bound Key for {str(addr)}")
            transport.set_subsystem_handler('sftp', paramiko.SFTPServer, Custom_Paramiko_SFTP)
            sftp_logger.debug(f"Added Subsystem handler for {str(addr)}")
            server = Underlying_SSH_Server()
            transport.start_server(server=server)
            sftp_logger.debug(f"Started Server for {str(addr)}")

            channels.append(transport.accept())
            # sftp_logger.debug(f"Channel Accepted")

            while transport.is_active():
                time.sleep(1)

    except Exception:
        sftp_logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
```

And the error generated is:

```
=== Key exchange agreements ===
Kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
HostKey: rsa-sha2-512
Cipher: aes256-ctr
MAC: hmac-sha1
Compression: none
=== End of kex handshake ===
kex engine KexCurve25519 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha256>
Switch to new keys ...
Started Server for ('31.117.38.192', 56391)
Exception (server): Invalid packet blocking
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2129, in run
    ptype, m = self.packetizer.read_message()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 487, in read_message
    raise SSHException("Invalid packet blocking")
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Invalid packet blocking
```

The key exchange algorithms seem to be agreed on properly checking both logs. WINSCP logs show:

```
. 2023-08-21 16:07:43.621 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) [aes256-ctr] outbound encryption
. 2023-08-21 16:07:43.621 Initialised HMAC-SHA-1 (bug-compatible) outbound MAC algorithm
. 2023-08-21 16:07:43.621 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) [aes256-ctr] inbound encryption
. 2023-08-21 16:07:43.621 Initialised HMAC-SHA-1 (bug-compatible) inbound MAC algorithm
. 2023-08-21 16:07:43.621 Incoming packet was garbled on decryption
. 2023-08-21 16:07:43.621 Attempt to close connection due to fatal exception:
* 2023-08-21 16:07:43.621 Incoming packet was garbled on decryption
. 2023-08-21 16:07:43.621 Closing connection.
. 2023-08-21 16:07:43.621 Selecting events 0 for socket 2764
* 2023-08-21 16:07:43.706 (EFatal) Incoming packet was garbled on decryption
* 2023-08-21 16:07:43.706 Authentication failed.
```

Digging into paramiko shows that invalid packet blocking is usually generated when there is no remaining body to a message after removing the heading. Whereas WINSCP seems to be getting a message that is not encrypted properly. I am struggling to see which side is causing the issue, if it's WINSCP I suspect an earlier misconfiguration of paramiko that then causes WINSCP to communicate incorrectly.

I am very much a begginner to paramiko and more high level networking and I'm only just starting to get a handle on what makes it function so am a little lost. A barebones client written in paramiko authenticates and connects properly with file exchange tested, I've tried with a google extension for sftp and that also fails to connect. What might be different between a basic SFTP client written in python and WINSCP and other fully blown SFTP clients?

What might be causing the issue here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDITS:
Reworked the question after further digging to emphasise clarity and remove superfulous information. Custom authentication code was originally included but I'm pretty sure that's not the issue so dropped it from the question.

Comment: `server_key = paramiko.RSAKey.generate(2048)` ? Why generating a new server key every time a new client connects?. It might not be the immediate cause of your error, but it is non-standard behavior. And regenerating this key for every client, means your server's identity changes with every connection, which can lead to trust issues for clients.

Comment: Also why the methods `_check_auth` in `Custom_Paramiko_SFTP` and `Underlying_SSH_Server` are almost identical? It is not an issue, but it is redundant.

Comment: Unfortunately the duplicate methods is left over from my initial attempts at getting it to work as was re-generating the key. I am very new to paramiko so trying to figure it out. However, I've fixed various bits and bobs now but still getting the same error. Interestingly a bare bones paramiko client that just connects, drops a file in and then drops the connection get's a lot further.